# Vue.js v-for in component renders when I visit the URL through a router-link but if I type the URL manually or refresh the page, v-for doesn't render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a pretty simple view that displays the icons of all characters from a certain game. If I were to visit the URL that displays that view through a router-link, everything works fine and I see the icons, however, if I then refresh the page, the icons disappear.

They also do not render at all if I manually type `www.example.com/champions`. Why is this happening.

My component:

```
<template>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class="champions-container">
            <div v-for='champion in champions' class="champion">
                <img class='responsive-image' :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/' + $store.getters.version + '/img/champion/' + champion.image.full" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                champions: this.$store.state.fullChampions
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my Vuex store where the champions are stored:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        version: null,
        fullChampions: null
    },
    mutations: {
        version(state, data){
            state.version = data.version
        },
        fullChampions(state, data){
            state.fullChampions = data.fullChampions
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getVersion({commit}){
            return axios.get("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/api/versions.json")
            .then((response) => {
                commit('version', {
                    version: response.data[0]
                })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        },
        getFullChampions({commit, state}){
            return axios.get("https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/" + state.version + "/data/en_US/championFull.json")
            .then((response) => {
                commit('fullChampions', {
                    fullChampions: Object.values(response.data.data)
                })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        },
```

Comment: where do you access getFullChampions() ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 Inside a mounted hook in my App.vue file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might be because of these issues you encountered.

**First:** that component is not the one that dispatched your getFullChampions function in your vuex, might be in other component.

**Second** is that, you are already assigning the value of champions wherein the state fullChampions is not updated.

```
this.champions: this.$store.state.fullChampions // state.fullChampions might not yet updated.
```

Try this one might help you

```
watch: {
      '$store.state.fullChampions': function() {
           this.champions = this.$store.state.fullChampions  
      },
}
```

**Last** is to to do first a condition above your v-for to prevent the element

```
<div class="champions-container" v-if=""$store.getters.version>
    <div v-for='champion in champions' class="champion">
        <img class='responsive-image' :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/' + $store.getters.version + '/img/champion/' + champion.image.full" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when I add the watcher for some reason - SyntaxError: C:\MAMP\htdocs\League Of Legends Frontend\src\views\Champions.vue: Unexpected token, expected ";" (20:26)

  18 |     watch: {
  19 |         '$store.state.fullChampions' () {
> 20 |             this.champions: this.$store.state.fullChampions  
     |                           ^
  21 |         },
  22 |     }

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add this:

```
watch: {
    $route: function(val, OldVal){
        this.champions = this.$store.state.fullChampions;
    }
},
```

after yuor `data`?

Upd.

If you are calling getFullChampions() action, then you can call it within watcher of my example instead of assigning to this.champions.